# How to make xml pretty using Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xml, pretty-print

I have xml displaying on browser that i want to make it pretty and indented.Is there any filter or expression in angularjs that can make readable for user.

html

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2default"><pre class="prettyprint lang-xml">{{string}}</pre></div>
```

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.string =  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="Process_1"> <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_2" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1"></bpmndi:BPMNPlane> </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram> </bpmn2:definitions>
```

Comment: do we have vkbeautify in bower ?

Comment: `bower install vkbeautify` should work.

Comment: That said, you could use any pretty printing library to do this, the key thing is that you have to wrap it using a filter/directive, as shown in the linked answer.

Comment: i have used directive as shown in linked answer but i got this error `angular.js:12808 TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`    on line in vkbeautify.js   `var ar = text.replace(/>\s*</g,"><")
     .replace(/</g,"~::~<")
     .replace(/\s*xmlns:/g,"~::~xmlns:")
     .replace(/\s*xmlns=/g,"~::~xmlns=")
     .split('~::~'),`   updated my html

Comment: Hi Hussain, Were you able to get a fix to the issue?